# Error Installing Tornado 4.0 Windows7 64bit

Tags: python, tornado

Help,

Am trying to install tornado 4.0 on my windows7 64bit but am getting the following error;

```
building 'tornado.speedups' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 176, in <module>
    **kwargs
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 9, in run
    self.build()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 111, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 85, in run
    build_ext.run(self)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 337, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 446, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "setup.py", line 97, in build_extension
    build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 496, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsall
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

Any ideas what am missing

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1115 which was reportedly due to a mismatch of 64-bit python and 32-bit visual c++.  The next release of Tornado (after 4.0) will skip the extension module and fall back to pure-python mode in this case.

Comment: You can set the environment variable TORNADO_EXTENSION=0 to skip the building of extensions.